# Firestore collection subscription pricing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I'm subscribing to a collection that has 1000 docs, will I bee charged for 1000 reads as soon as the subscription is initiated? Per https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#listens I'd say no, but per https://stackoverflow.com/a/60356400/9118098 I'd say yes.

I'm asking as I have an "ever-growing" calendarEvents collections, and am trying do decide whether it'd be better to structure data as

calendarEvents/{calendarEventId}

or

calendarEvents/{2022}/March/{calendarEventId}

to keep the cost down, as the latter allows me to subscribe to the current month only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by subscription you mean Firestore listeners then you are charged based on the number of document retrieved by the listener.

For example, your collection has 1000 documents and you add a listener on the whole collection then you'll be charged 1000 reads for those documents and 1 read for each subsequent update received. If you add some query clause such as `where(field, "==", value)` and let's say this matched and returned only 700 documents,  then you'll be charged 700 reads for initial read and 1 for each update received.